# Adding a custom JSONB text_field tag with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have a JSONB type `options` column on a model in my Rails application and I am in a situation where I need to provide JSONB nested parameters manually for every single form. That's why the official solution proposed [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-inputs-for-key-value-hash-attributes) is not an option.

So I might want to have something like:

```
options[first_name], options[last_name]
```

for one instance, and a totally different set for another:

```
options[pet_dog], options[frank_sinatra]
```

I assume it can well be implemented using something like

```
= f.text_field :options[pet_dog]
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution code looks like this:

View form:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :options do |p|
  - @options.each do |o|
    = p.input o.name.to_sym, input_html: {value: o.default_value}
```

Controller

```
def new
  @options = Model.options
  ...
end

def create
  @job  = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)
end

...

def job_params
  params.require(:job_request).permit(
  ...
  options: get_options)
end

def get_options
  some_model.options.pluck(:name).map(&:to_sym)
end
```

Possibly this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

How did you implement the jsonb column? Have you added this to the model?

```
serialize :options, HashSerializer
store_accessor :options, :pet_dog, :pet_cat, :pet_cow
```

*Note that HashSerializer is a class acting as a serializer, which looks like this:

```
class HashSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash.to_json
  end

  def self.load(hash)
    (hash || {}).with_indifferent_access
  end
end
```

What those 2 lines on the model do is allowing you using accessor (getter and setter) for the json/jsonb keys. So you can do this:

```
object = Model.new
object.pet_dog = 'Dog1'
object.pet_cat = 'Cat1'
object.options = {"pet_dog"=>"Dog1", "pet_cat"=>"Cat1"}
```

Which in turn, allows you to use it as form fields:

```
f.text_field :pet_dog
f.text_field :pet_cat
```

Do not forget to whitelist the attributes in the strong_params method

You can read more on this comprehensive post by Nando Vieira: 
http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Also, if you want a shortcut, there is a gem for this: 
https://github.com/devmynd/jsonb_accessor